# Where Sonar is storing test results?

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage, sonarqube

I was working with Sonar and I was confused, when I've connected to Sonar DB. I was trying to find scan results (for example, code coverage or test success %) and I've failed with that. As my sonar web app is down, I cannot check them, but I want to see them.

What i have found, that Sonar has MEASURE_DATA table, which have measure Id's and results in BLOB. But how can i find which one is the one I need? In DB there are no foreign keys connected to these fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use the Web Service API instead of directly quering the database. The DB model is always subject for modifications. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API

Comment: Thanks. But actually, I've found everything in project_measures table.

Comment: Nobody assures that the project_measures table will remain the same in future versions. Web Services API won't change even if the underlying database will :)